# Filter from specified columns and display results into 1 column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I've got 2 sheets setup with exactly the same format (need to split up data because sheets are getting too long) and I'm currently able to filter through 1 column, see if there's any content, and if there is, to display a corresponding cell from that row into a new column. Problem is, I want to be able to search through multiple sheets within the same document, and pull all the relevant results. I don't know how to have it output the results into a single column.

`=IFERROR(FILTER(Data1!C4:C,(Data1!E4:E<>"")*(Data2!E4:E<>"")),"")`

Here you can see I'm filtering and pulling data from 2 columns, one from Data1 starting in column E4 and down, and one also from Data2 column E4 and down, and if it matches my criteria, it displays the data I have in column C. Currently this is working as is, but I don't know how to add in Data2 (Data2!C4:C) into the mix. It's only bringing in from Data1 which is all I've got defined in that formula. I get errors anytime I try injecting Data2. I just don't know enough about proper syntax with this... any help would be great!

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Would you please clarify a few things? 1) _need to split up data because sheets are getting too long_ How many actual rows and columns of data are in each sheet? 2) Have you tried creating a second formula for "Data2", and "stacking" the results of both formulas in an array (using curly brackets)?

Comment: Splitting data into multiple sheets is usually not the best strategy. You may want to consolidate the data back into one sheet and use tools like [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to manage the data. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [{ array expressions }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) to stack the data, like this:

`=filter( { Data1!C4:C; Data2!C4:C }, { len(Data1!E4:E); len(Data2!E4:E) } )`

Comment: Yes! @doubleunary that worked perfectly! Thank you!